# How do you add external libraries to intellij project during setup?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When making a new java project with intellij, I cannot find any option for adding external libraries. The only way I have found is to make a lib folder after making the project and putting the jar files there, but that involves copying and pasting. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: you might want to use gradle or maven and their package management system.

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: Are you using Maven or not?

Comment: I will probably use gradle for it, because android also uses cradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the File>Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) there is a tab named libraries -> Click on + -> Libraries

Also you can create a project in which the dependencies are managed by Gradle or Maven. Depending on the library you want to import, there use to be a section on the website of each library dedicated to guiding how to import in Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Thank you!  I found that but for whatever reason it wasn't working, but it now works!